# How to name an array or object after a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a javascript noob.  What I would like to do is take the name of my selector id and use it as the name for another array.  I get all types of errors when I try to code this :(

```
var this.id = {};
```

or

```
var string(this.id) = {};
```

gives back some nasty errors :(

The this refers to my current selector and is the input I am using.  this.id is giving me the proper string for the input ID.  So that works, at least according to console.log()

This is what I am trying to do...

```
myObject = 
{"ID of selector" = {variable A = 123, variable B = 493, variable C = 293},
    "ID of selector" = {variable A = 493, variable B = 492, variable C = 342}    
}
```

Thanks for all help!

Comment: methinks you want [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from ECMAScript 6, of cource if you want `this.id` will be object, if `this.id` is `string` then simple object enought

Comment: You cannot do that with `var` variables. Use an object, like the `myObject = {}` in your example, for dynamically keyed data stores.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you intent using the array/dictionary notation like:

```
var myObject = {};   
myObject["ID of selector"] = {"foo" : 1};
```

However you cannot access `"ID of selector"` like a property of the object but only as dictionary like:

```
myObject["ID of selector"].foo //<- outpus 1 using sample above
```